# can not install mvn 3.3.3 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: maven, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I need to run `mvn 3.3.3`. Currently, the installed mvn version 3.0.5. When I enter

`sudo apt-get install maven`

it says 
`maven is already the newest version`

is there a way to force install mvn 3.3.3?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add a ppa containing maven 3.3.3, for example [this one](https://launchpad.net/%7Eandrei-pozolotin/+archive/ubuntu/maven3) by executing these  instructions on the command-line:

```
sudo apt-get purge maven maven2 maven3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andrei-pozolotin/maven3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install maven3
```

Comment: btw, I never know where I should look up the ppa. How do you search for it?

Comment: ppa are repos that contain specific, non standard packages. You don't have everything, but it's easy to use when you find the goog one

Comment: thanks that worked ... why not the original people maven guys work and maintain a standard repo ??

Comment: they probably don't maintain packaging for old ubuntus versions

Answer (score 7):

If you are not comfortable with a PPA (***personal*** package archive) where you have no assurance of the provenance this is an alternative.

*From a security perspective if you don't know where it came from don't install it.*

In my linked [article](https://www.tomred.net/devops/install-the-latest-version-of-maven-on-linux.html) I retrieve the latest file from apache which is a known and trusted source. You can get the latest version

```
\#identify the latest version of maven
    latest=$(curl http://www-us.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/ | tac | sed -ne 's/[^0-9]*\(\([0-9]\.\)\{0,3\}[0-9]\).*/\1/p' | head -1)
\#download it
    wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/$latest/binaries/apache-maven-$latest-bin.tar.gz
```

then install it from

```
\#Unpack it
    sudo tar -zxf apache-maven-$latest-bin.tar.gz -C /usr/local/
\#create a sym link to it
    sudo ln -s /usr/local/apache-maven-$latest/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
```

as outlined in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed maven 3.2.5. 
To do that I downloaded the version I wanted as noted.

Unzipped using: tar -xvf apache-maven-3.2.5-bin.tar.gz

to: /opt/ and let p7zip do its thing.

Then in the terminal I did the following:

1. Check environment variable value:
   echo $JAVA_HOME
2. Adding to PATH:

export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin:$PATH

3. typed:  mvn -v

reviewed the output

For me the above worked fine.